# Build a CNN with theano in batch mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, deep-learning, theano

i'm trying to build a CNN with theano works in batch mode: i want that at the end of the convolutional-pooling layers start a complete MLP training (for example 100 iteration), get from this latter the cost, so that i can estiamte the gradient and the updates. I'm following this [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html). 
So i have create a conv-pool layer class and a MLP class (one hidden layer plus a logistic regression layer). The only differences are that the conv-pool have a method 'buildLayer' to build the layer when the input is given:

```
class CPLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, rng, filter_shape, image_shape, pool_size=(2, 2)):
        self.rng=rng
        self.filter_shape=filter_shape
        self.image_shape=image_shape
        self.pool_size=pool_size

    def buildLayer(self, input):

        fan_out = (self.filter_shape[0] * np.prod(self.filter_shape[2:]) //
                   np.prod(self.pool_size))
        W_bound = np.sqrt(6. / (fan_in + fan_out))
        self.W = theano.shared(np.asarray(self.rng.uniform(low=-W_bound, high=W_bound, size=self.filter_shape),dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True)

        # the bias is a 1D tensor -- one bias per output feature map
        b_values = np.zeros((self.filter_shape[0],), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
        self.b = theano.shared(value=b_values, borrow=True)

        # convolve input feature maps with filters
        conv_out = conv2d(input=input,filters=self.W,
        filter_shape=self.filter_shape,
        input_shape=self.image_shape
        )

        # pool each feature map individually, using maxpooling
        pooled_out = pool.pool_2d(
             input=conv_out,
             ds=self.pool_size,
             ignore_border=True
        )

        self.output = T.tanh(pooled_out + self.b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))

        # store parameters of this layer
        self.params = [self.W, self.b]

        # keep track of model input
        self.input = input
```

The CNN class:

```
class CNN(dict):
    def __init__(self, n_layers, nkerns, batch_size, n_out, image_size):

        self.nkerns=nkerns
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        self.n_layers=n_layers
        self.n_out=n_out
        self.image_size=image_size

    def setConvPoolParameters(self, id_layer, filter_size=(5,5), pool_size=(2,2), mode='max', type='tanh', alpha=0):
        if id_layer==0:
            image_size=self.image_size
        else:
            image_size=[(self[id_layer-1].image_shape[2+i]-self[id_layer-1].filter_shape[2+i]+1)//self[id_layer-1].pool_size[i] for i in range(2)]

         image_shape=(self.batch_size, (1 if id_layer==0 else self.nkerns[id_layer-1]), image_size[0], image_size[1])
         filter_shape=(self.nkerns[id_layer], (1 if id_layer==0 else self.nkerns[id_layer-1]), filter_size[0], filter_size[1])
        self[id_layer]=CPLayer(rng=self.rng, filter_shape=filter_shape, image_shape=image_shape, pool_size=pool_size)

    def setModelParameters(self, model_name='MLP', **kwargs):
        n_in=self.nkerns[-1]*(self[self.n_layers-1].image_shape[2]-self[self.n_layers-1].filter_shape[2]+1)//self[self.n_layers-1].pool_size[0]*(self[self.n_layers-1].image_shape[3]-self[self.n_layers-1].filter_shape[3]+1)//self[self.n_layers-1].pool_size[1]
        self[self.n_layers]=MLP(name=model_name, rng=self.rng, n_in=n_in, n_out=self.n_out, kwargs=kwargs)


    def evaluate(self, learning_rate=0.1, n_epochs=1, printOut=0):  

        dataset='mnist.pkl.gz'

        datasets = load_data(dataset)

        train_set_x, train_set_y = datasets[0]
        valid_set_x, valid_set_y = datasets[1]
        test_set_x, test_set_y = datasets[2]

        # compute number of minibatches for training, validation and testing
        n_train_batches = train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
        n_valid_batches = valid_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
        n_test_batches = test_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
        n_train_batches //= self.batch_size
        n_valid_batches //= self.batch_size
        n_test_batches //= self.batch_size

        # allocate symbolic variables for the data
        index = T.lscalar()  # index to a [mini]batch

        x = T.matrix('x')   # the data is presented as rasterized images
        y = T.ivector('y')  # the labels are presented as 1D vector of
                        # [int] labels

        ######################
        # BUILD ACTUAL MODEL #
        ######################
        print('... building the model')

        # Reshape matrix of rasterized images of shape (batch_size, 28 * 28)
        # to a 4D tensor, compatible with our LeNetConvPoolLayer
        # (28, 28) is the size of MNIST images.
        layer0_input = x.reshape((self.batch_size, 1, self.image_size[0], self.image_size[1]))

        self[0].buildLayer(layer0_input)
        for id_layer in range(1, self.n_layers):        
            self[id_layer].buildLayer(self[id_layer-1].output)

        layerN_input=self[self.n_layers-1].output.flatten(2)
        self[self.n_layers].buildModel(layerN_input)


        params=[]
        for id_layer in range(self.n_layers-1, -1, -1):
            params += self[id_layer].params 
        self.params=params

        cost = self[self.n_layers].train(y)
        grads = T.grad(cost, params)
        updates = [(param_i, param_i - learning_rate * grad_i) for param_i, grad_i in zip(params, grads)]


        train = theano.function(
            inputs=[index],
            outputs=cost,
            updates=updates,
            givens={
                x: train_set_x[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size],
                y: train_set_y[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
            }
         )
```

So when i call 'self[self.n_layers].train(y)', i call a MLP method:

```
class MLP(object):
    def __init__(self, rng, n_in, n_hidden, n_out, learning_rate=None, L1_reg=None, L2_reg=None, n_epochs=None):
        learning_rate=learning_rate if not learning_rate is None else 0.01
        L1_reg=L1_reg if not L1_reg is None else 0.00
        L2_reg=L2_reg if not L2_reg is None else 0.0001
        n_epochs=n_epochs if not n_epochs is None else 100 


        self.rng=rng
        self.n_in=n_in
        self.n_hidden=n_hidden
        self.n_out=n_out
        self.learning_rate=learning_rate
        self.L1_reg=L1_reg
        self.L2_reg=L2_reg
        self.n_epochs=n_epochs

    def buildModel(self, input):
        self.input=input
        self.hiddenLayer = HiddenLayer(
            rng=self.rng,
            input=self.input,
            n_in=self.n_in,
            n_out=self.n_hidden,
            activation=T.tanh
        )

        self.logRegressionLayer = LogisticRegression(
            input=self.hiddenLayer.output,
            n_in=self.n_hidden,
            n_out=self.n_out
        )
        self.L1 = (
            abs(self.hiddenLayer.W).sum()
            + abs(self.logRegressionLayer.W).sum()
        )

        self.L2_sqr = (
            (self.hiddenLayer.W ** 2).sum()
            + (self.logRegressionLayer.W ** 2).sum()
        )

        self.params = self.logRegressionLayer.params +self.hiddenLayer.params 

        self.negative_log_likelihood = (
            self.logRegressionLayer.negative_log_likelihood
        )
        self.errors = self.logRegressionLayer.errors

    def train(self, y):#, input, y):
        start_time = timeit.default_timer()
        epoch = -1
        done_looping = False
        self.updates_list=[]
        while (epoch < self.n_epochs) and (not done_looping):
            epoch = epoch + 1
            self.cost=(self.negative_log_likelihood(y) + self.L1_reg*self.L1 + self.L2_reg*self.L2_sqr)
            self.gparams = [T.grad(self.cost, param) for param in self.params]
            self.updates = [(param, param - self.learning_rate * gparam) for param, gparam in zip(self.params, self.gparams)]
            batch_avg_cost = self.cost

            self.updates_list.append(copy.deepcopy(self.updates))

        end_time = timeit.default_timer()
        return batch_avg_cost
```

Now I can not understand why None of the parameters is updated. One of you know the reason??
Thanks.